# Is there a common unit of measurement for comparison of computing power used to solve mathematical puzzles?

Tags: computation-models

I just wanted to make sure if I'm reasoning correctly. So, if two computers are solving the same mathematical puzzle i.e. SHA-256 function of Bitcoin (finding nonce that satisfies difficulty target), the computing power used by each of them can be compared in units of Gigahashes, Terahashes etc. and we know which one used more computing power in time.
But what if we wanted to compare computing power (herein called "CP") used by two computers in time t if those two computers were solving different hash functions (e.g. one SHA-256 and one SHA 3-512) or different mathematical functions altogether?
Could we then denominate computation power used by Computer 1 and 2 to reach a conclusion that in time t:
Computer's 1 CP > Computer's 2 CP
and by how much? And what would be that proper and best denominator (FLOPS, MIPS, IPS..)?

Comment: It depends on lots of factors. It seems that your question will not have a definitive answer. Are you actually interested in a more restricted question? Say, how are the most powerful supercomputers are ranked?

Comment: Question is definitive. What factors, in your opinion, should be taken into perspective? Could you elaborate? Question is about unit of measurement for general comparison of computing power used to solve a given mathematical puzzle, where the puzzle is referent, but the set of puzzles and their kind is not determined in the question.

Comment: A math puzzle can be a problem about 3D drawing. A math puzzle could be about symbolic computation. Almost any computational problem can be considered as  a part of a math puzzle. A computer with some GPU might be better for graphic problems.

Comment: For many problems, there are computers built specifically for them. People are building specific computers to compute neural network/artificial intelligence. Specific computers have been built for Bitcoin farming.

Comment: Solving some problems needs enormous space inherently. The memory size of a computer should be considered as an important part of the power for those problem.

Comment: Input and output speed and volume should be considered as well.

Comment: The list can go on and on. Is the ability to generate massive randomness a special kind of computing power? I would think so, even though you might disagree.

Comment: If you are only concerned about the clock speed and floating point computations, you might be just interested in the ranking of supercomputers.

Comment: [cross](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/66150/is-there-a-common-unit-of-measurement-for-comparison-of-computing-power-used-to) posting is not a good ethic on SO. You should stick one and wait for answers/responses.

Comment: Sorry for cross-posting. I apologized in cryptography forum for that.

Comment: Simply, if I am a Bitcoin node, I can evaluate two blockchains in terms of each one consisting of more Terahashes than the other and thus deduct which one is the "correct" one. There is impartial source of consensus - hashes done. But what if I had two blockchains, each one making a different function, e.g. one is Bitcoin and making SHA-256 and another is making other random computation. Could I impartially deduct which "chain" has the most computation power spent even if in those two chains the "way" this computation power is spent is different? Is there common impartial denominator then?

Comment: Can you add your clarification to the question? Comment are not assumed to be read by people and search engine. Ignore math puzzles. It is already difficult or interesting enough to answer your specific concern on comparing the computation needed for two blockchains.

Comment: Once you update your question, I will remove all my distracting comments.

Comment: **"computing energy" or "computing work"** is the appropriate term than "computing power" here.